# Running Shell commands and scripts from PHP - is there a correct and secure way?

Tags: php, apache, shell, centos, shell-exec

I developed and operate a bespoke E-Commerce platform for a variety of customers. I want to automate some of the setup tasks, such as creating apache site config files, and installing SSL Certificates.

I have written some batch files which do both of those nicely, and I want to execute them as part of the PHP Site creation process.

I have been able to run one of these scripts using the shell_exec command in PHP, but I am confused about the permissions and concerned about security. This is all hosted on Centos Linux, and Apache web server by the way.

My batch script (create_site_config.sh) effectively generates an Apache config file for a given site and copies it to /etc/httpd/conf.d/ as 'domain.com.conf'.

The problem is, is that PHP generates this file under the ownership of apache:apache, whereas all the rest of the files in this folder are owned by root:root.

In my batch script if I use SUDO before my commands, nothing happens. Whereas if I omit SUDO, the scripts runs and creates the file for me, but under the wrong ownership. I am not able to change the ownership either.

So my PHP is something like this:

`shell_exec('./create_site_config.sh);`

And my batch file is something like this:

```
DOMAIN=$1
SYSNAME=$2

if [ -z "$1" ]
  then
    echo "You must pass a fully qualified domain as the first argument, ie. acme.dev.domain.com"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z "$2" ]
  then
    echo "You must pass a sysname as the second argument, ie acme"
    exit 1
fi

#THESE COMMANDS CLEARLY RUN AS APACHE:APACHE. IF I PUT
#SUDO IN FRONT OF THEM, THEY DON't WORK AT ALL - WHAT GIVES?
rm -f ${DOMAIN}.conf
touch ${DOMAIN}.conf
chmod 777 ${DOMAIN}.conf

#START OF FILE CONTENT
cat >> ${DOMAIN}.conf <<EOL

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/siteroot
    ServerName ${DOMAIN}

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3

    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn

    <Directory "/var/www/html/portals.dev">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLCertificateFile /home/centos/.ssh/live_keys/${SYSNAME}_cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/centos/.ssh/live_keys/${SYSNAME}_key.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /home/centos/.ssh/live_keys/${SYSNAME}_fullchain.pem
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ${DOMAIN}
    Redirect 301 / https://${DOMAIN}
</VirtualHost>

EOL
#END OF FILE CONTENT

#CLEAN UP
cp ${DOMAIN}.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/sites/${DOMAIN}.conf

#THIS COMMAND BELOW DOESN'T WORK...
sudo chmod 644 /etc/httpd/conf.d/sites/${DOMAIN}.conf 
#NEITHER DOES THIS ONE...
chown root:root /etc/httpd/conf.d/sites/${DOMAIN}.conf

rm -f ${DOMAIN}.conf
sudo systemctl reload httpd.service

echo "success"
```

What is the correct way to do this in a away that will ensure that the files are created and that I can set the permissons of them.

Despite the above working I sense that it is not secure to do things this way. I don't understand why SUDO doesn't work in the batch script?

Clearly systems like Plesk and Cpanel are able to generate all kinds of system files and folders - what sort of techniques do they use?

I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Regards

James

Comment: Have you tried changing your user to `apache` (`su - apache`) and running the commands yourself to see the output? Perhaps `apache` isn't a sudo'er?

Comment: I did see something about adding apache as a sudo'er but the syntax provided in the article actually broke my sudo file. Perhaps I'll look at that again then. So this would allow Apache to be/run SUDO then? Thanks by the way!